# WinRT User Selectable Theme

Tags: windows-runtime, themes

I have a WinRT Application, and I would like the user to be able to select themes, can I define other theme's, besides Light/Dark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not built into the platform currently, so you would need to implement it yourself. The way I would do it would be to replace resource dictionaries at app level and recreate the visual tree when switching dictionaries (e.g. remove and add back the entire control tree - the root Frame, current Page etc. The StaticResource bindings never update so you need to force reevaluation and that should be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Filip, how can I do this? I'm trying to change some resources at runtime and they don't show up unless I restart the app. I'm assuming it's due to the StaticResource bindings not updating, like you said. Can you give an example on how to do this?

Comment: StaticResources are static so they don't re-evaluate unless they need to. I'm not sure when exactly they are loaded, but you could try what I mentioned - remove the Frame from Window.Current.Content and then add it or a new instance back. Navigate to a new instance of the page etc.

Comment: Of course it's also possible that since I've tried it last - the platform got somehow smarter and is caching the resources, so you'll need to restart the app to refresh them, but I'd still try.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Currently I'm changing my app to do `( (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["key"] ).Color = color;` This works. What I was doing before was I had a template that I was replacing a bunch of things on, then loading it as a xaml resource and setting that resource. I'll try the Frame thing.